# Regex to validate a string has only cookie based data

Tags: python, regex

so i am using the following regex `(\w+)=([^\s]+)` to validate if a string is a valid cookie string, for simple key value paired string this works fine, but it should work for some thing below

```
Acceptable--> "key1=val1;key2=val2;"
Unacceptable--> "key1=val1;;;key2=val2;;;key3=val3"
```

Any help will be apperciated.

Comment: Try `^\w+=[^;]+(?:;\w+=[^;]+)*;$`, or - if the `;` at the end is optional - ``^\w+=[^;]+(?:;\w+=[^;]+)*;?$``

Comment: You may use: `^(?:\w+=[^;]+;)+$`

Comment: @anubhava: thanks for answering how to have an optional space between key value pairs e.g `key1=val1; key2=val2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to match one or more of `key=value;` pairs followed by optional spaces:

```
^(?:\s*\w+\s*=\s*[^;]*;)+$
```

Assumes that there is always a `;` in the end.
[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6pyy3J/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
  - `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - `=`: Match a `=`
  - `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - `[^;]+`: Match 1+ non-semicolon characters
  - `;`: Match a `;`
- `)+`:  End non-capture group. `+` lets this group match one or more times
- `$`: End

Comment: Thanks , for you reply i tried switching sting, `"coding=helloworld;foobar=demo;random=error"
"hello=world;;;"` this string is failing can you please see what could be changed?

Comment: It is failing due to 3 semi-colons at the end. There should be only one i.e. `coding=helloworld;foobar=demo;random=error" "hello=world;`

Comment: i made some change `"(\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+;)+(\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+)?"` please see if this makes sense

Comment: A correct one would be: `^(?:\s*\w+\s*=\s*[^;]*;)+$`

Comment: The last 1 was correct, please update answer, i will accept, thanks alt